# Hbase and Phoenix can't able to map integers

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

i'm trying to map an hbase table with phoenix but result table gives null value in the column with integer values.

this is my hbase table

```
create 'foo2', {NAME => 'cf', VERSIONS => 5}, {NAME => 'cn'}
put 'foo2', '1' , 'cf:ID', '1'
put 'foo2', '1' , 'cf:c1', 'a'
put 'foo2', '1' , 'cf:c2', 'b'
put 'foo2', '1' , 'cn:idFoo3', 1

put 'foo2', '2' , 'cf:ID', '2'
put 'foo2', '2' , 'cf:c1', 'c'
put 'foo2', '2' , 'cf:c2', 'd'
put 'foo2', '2' , 'cn:idFoo3', 2
```

and this is my phoenix mapping

```
create view "foo2" (ID INTEGER primary key, "cf"."c1" VARCHAR, "cf"."c2" VARCHAR, "cn"."idFoo3" INTEGER);
```

opening the table with squirrel i have null values for ID column and error for idFoo3 values

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing 'cn:idFoo3' as a **String** with value "1" and "2". Similar reasoning applies to cf:ID. HBase shell takes the value as a **String**.

I would recommend you to use Phoenix to insert data into your Phoenix tables. Also, Phoenix serialization format is slightly different from HBase.

Comment: i can't understand.. now i'm triying import a table with sqoop,
   ` sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://<connection>" --query "SELECT  Id,Date FROM test_table WHERE \$CONDITIONS " --split-by Date --hbase-create-table --hbase-table test_table --column-family tt --columns "Id,Date" --map-column-java StartDate=java.sql.Timestamp --hbase-row-key Id`

then i try to map with phoenix in this way:

`create view "test_table"(Id INTEGER, "tt"."Date" TIMESTAMP)`

but data isn't correct, for example Id: -1271779280 and Date: 177670840-01-03 20:39:51.808525873

what's wrong in my mapping?

Comment: @ntrax: Again, you are doing the same mistake of importing data as String. Sqoop doesnt import data in non-string data types in HBase. Please go through http://phoenix.apache.org/language/index.html to understand how to insert data into Phoenix via "insert" statements. You can also use CSV bulk loader of Phoenix.

Comment: first of all, thanks for your help. 
look to this table:

create 'foo2', {NAME => 'cf', VERSIONS => 5}
put 'foo2', '1' , 'cf:ID', '1'
put 'foo2', '1' , 'cf:c1', 'r1-c1'
put 'foo2', '1' , 'cf:c2', 'r1-c2'
put 'foo2', '1' , 'cf:idFoo2', '1'

if i map it as:
create view "foo2" ("cf"."c1" VARCHAR, "cf"."c2" VARCHAR, "cf"."idFoo2" VARCHAR);

i can see in idFoo2 field the "1" value but if i map the table in this way:

create view "foo2" ("cf"."c1" VARCHAR, "cf"."c2" VARCHAR, "cf"."idFoo2" INTEGER);

looking in SQuirreL idFoo2 has an <error> value but idFoo2 metadata are correctly mapped as integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think in **hbase shell** your **put** date is string default.
You should use Apache Phoenix's APIs for writing data to Phoenix tables
such as

```
put.addColumn("i".getBytes(), "count".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(sum));
```

and in **hbase shell** the data looks like below,and you should use UNSIGNED_INT to mapping as [datatypes](http://phoenix.apache.org/language/datatypes.html) described.

```
hbase(main):030:0> scan 'wordcount'
ROW                             COLUMN+CELL                                                                                
 Apache                         column=i:_0, timestamp=1498293255970, value=                                               
 Apache                         column=i:count, timestamp=1498293255970, value=\x00\x00\x00\x01
```

my mapping sql is like this

```
create  table "wordcount"(
    pk VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY
    ,"i"."count" UNSIGNED_INT
)
```